# For an infinite set, if $A\times A$ and $A$ have the same cardinality, then there is an injection from $\mathbb N$ to $A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Could someone help me with this question, please?

> If there is a bijection between $A$ and $A\times A$ then prove that there is an injective function from $\mathbb N$ to $A$?

Where $A$ is infinite set and $\mathbb N$ is the set of natural numbers.

Comment: How do you define "infinite"?

Comment: by the number of elements

Comment: @MaramOs: How do you define "the number of elements"?

Comment: and if A is finite there is no a bijection between A and AxA

Comment: By this definition, a singleton and an empty set are not finite, and they form counterexamples to what you are asking.

Comment: @tomasz if A is finite iff if there is a bijection between A and finite subset of N if it is not then A is infinite.

Answer (score 3):

This is false if $A$ has one element or $A=\varnothing$, of course. But otherwise, this is true.

This can be done in two non-trivial steps:

1. Show that if for every $x\notin A$, there is a bijection between $A$ and $A\cup\{x\}$, then there is an injection from $\Bbb N$ into $A$.
2. Show that if there is a bijection from $A$ to $A\times A$ ***and*** there are at least two elements in $A$, then $A\cup\{x\}$ has cardinality at most $A\times A$. This goes easily through showing that $A\times\{0,1\}$ has the same cardinality as $A$, and therefore $A\cup\{x\}$ and $A$ also have the same cardinality.

   The Cantor-Bernstein theorem is heavily utilized in this part of the proof.

Comment: why do i need to prove there is a bijection between A and A∪{x} ? and how?

Comment: Huh? Where did I say that?

Comment: can you explain number one?

Comment: What's unclear exactly?

Comment: why I need to prove there is a bijection between A and A with intersection x? can I prove in another way? and how can I use symbols?

Comment: You are not reading this right. Read again the first step. Tell me where it says that you need to prove there is a bijection between $A$ and $A\cup\{x\}$.

Comment: you said show that if for every x not in A there is bijection between A and A with intersection is it the same? and why ?

Comment: That is not what I wrote there. Read it again, carefully this time.

Comment: Do you mean !!  i need to prove A with intersection x has cardinality the same as AxA and {0,1} x A?How?

Comment: (1) Stop writing "intersection", this is clearly not intersection. (2) For chrissakes, I gave you two not-very-hard-to-prove steps. Analyze them carefully. All the follow up questions you've asked me thus far were the result of sloppy reading of my answer. Hints don't have to be of the type that spoonfeed you a half-chewed answer, they could also be of the type that just show you the general direction on the map, and you still have to figure out the terrain.

Comment: So again, prove that from *an* assumption, you can find an injection from the naturals into $A$; then show that *the* assumption of your question, you can prove that the previous "an assumption" holds, and therefore there is an injection from the natural numbers into $A$ a you want to show.

Comment: my big problem is i do not know how can i defined a new injective function and i want to know how elements of A look like to help me with defining.

Comment: I think i find two injective functions as you said but it is hard to write down here so now why there is an injective function between N into A?

Comment: I got 1 out of 5 in this question and I'm still wondering about your answer? i have explain to me I will be glad of you, thank you.